# How to find MAX of a time type column from an imported csv table in R?

Tags: r

Hi I am completely new to R-programming, for a project need to find the **max of a time type column** from an imported csv file.

preview of the column: of the time type format **%H:%M:%S**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNORJ.png)

table name : **X202302_divvy_tripdata**

Code used to find the MAX:

```
library(chron)
ride_length_chron <- chron(times. = combined_table$ride_length)
max_ride_length <- max(ride_length_chron)
max_ride_length_format <- format(max_ride_length, format. = "%H:%M:%S")
max_ride_length_format
```

In this code I am getting an **error** as the output is showing as : **"NA"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the `chron` package, but this seems to work if you have a character variable after you've imported your data:

```r
library(chron)

# assertion to check data type since this is not clear in the question
stopifnot(class(combined_table$ride_length) == "character")

ride_times <- times(combined_table$ride_length)
max(ride_times)
```

If you have missing values in the `ride_length` column, you can either change the raw data, or exclude the missing values when calculating the maximum:

```r
max(ride_times, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The times function within the `chron` package returns at `times` class which is non-standard. After calculating your maximum time, you could coerce the value to a character if easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! there were NA values so it was not working. Now it is working fine

Comment: Great - if you think the answer is correct, can you accept it so that it's removed from the "unanswered" pile?